# Why is naming a String variable, String, a valid Java construct?

Tags: java

Given this case:

```
    String String = ""; //valid
```

Why is this valid?

Also, why is it that:

```
    int int = 0;  // is invalid
```

I'm baffled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a reserved keyword.  Reserved keywords may not be used as part of [any formal variable name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) - the same is true of `true`, `false`, and `null` as literals.  [There's a list of those such keywords available.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)

`String` is a class name and cannot be a reserved keyword.  This is because you cannot predict what the name of a class will be in *general*.

By convention, reserved keywords are lower case, variable names are camelCased, and classes are TitleCased.  Following these conventions will ensure that your code doesn't run into these simple errors.

Answer (score 2):

Reserved words can't be used in variable names.

List of reserved words:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Same goes for class names.